# REST API call returns 404 error in Google App Engine with PHP Yii2 framework

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My application contains Angular and Php Yii2 framework.

I hosted my application on Google App Engine.

Here is the contents of my app.yaml file:

```
threadsafe: true
runtime: php55
api_version: 2

handlers:

# The root URL (/) is handled by the Go application.
# No other URLs match this pattern.

- url: /(.+)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*)

- url: /web-service/*
  script: web-service/yii

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

[image]

My Yii2 library is available in web-service directory, but when I call REST API from the postman, it then returns a '404 page not found' error.

Am I missing something in my app.yaml file?

Please help me solve this issue. My API call is something like this:

https://abcxyz.appspot.com/web-service/web/user-registration/login-user

Answer (score 1):

Several problems:

- `api_version: 2` - there is no such version presently, set it to `1`. From the **api_version** row in the [Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#syntax) table:

  > At this time, App Engine has one version of the php runtime
  >   environment: 1
- the order of the handlers in `app.yaml` matters, the first one with a matching pattern will be used. Your `url: /(.+)` pattern will match all of your `/web-service/*` requests as well, so static files uploads will be attempted instead of the script(s) you're expecting. Re-order your handlers with the most significant patterns preceeding the less significant ones.
- your `script: web-service/yii` entry *might* not be OK if other php files need to be served from the `web-service` dir (the `web-service/yii` will always be the one served, regardless of the requested script). Instead I'd use the handler suggested in the [Example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#example) (assuming the script names always end with `.php`):

  > ```
  > # Serve php scripts.
  > - url: /(.+\.php)$
  >   script: \1
  > ```

Always check the request entries in the development server logs as a starting point to debug request failures.